# Rest-Assured unable to validate JSON array response

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, hamcrest, rest-assured-jsonpath

I'm trying to validate that a JSON array contains a certain value. Using Rest-Assured with a hamcrest matchers import in Java. This is the JSON that I'm validating;

```
{
    "graph": {
        "groupedResultColumns": [
            "Task_Status",
            "Task_TimeSpent"
        ]
    }
}
```

After reading about rest assured and hamcrest matchers, this is the code that I am trying at the moment;

```
{
    SerenityRest.then()
      .body(containsString("groupedResultColumns"))
      .assertThat().body("groupedResultColumns", (hasItems("Task_TimeSpent")));
}
```

This is the error I'm getting;

```
JSON path groupedResultColumns doesn't match.
Expected: (a collection containing "Task_TimeSpent")
  Actual: null
```

Any help or advice is appreciated, 
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about SerenityRest but... are you sure that groupedResultColumns is selected? Maybe you should select graph first?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the json path to the collection. The `"groupedResultColumns"` is inside `"graph"` so your path to the body would be `graph.groupedResultColumns`.

Your code would be something like this:

```
{
    SerenityRest.then()
      .body(containsString("groupedResultColumns"))
      .assertThat().body("graph.groupedResultColumns", (hasItems("Task_TimeSpent")));
}
```